# What does this definition of a sequence mean?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I came across this problem in a book of mixed mathematical excersices:

A sequence $a_1,a_2,...$ we denote with $(a_n)$. A sequence $(a_n)$ of positive numbers $a_n$ is said to be a "*zero-sequence*" if there for every $ε > 0$ exist an integer $n_ε \geq 1$ such that $a_n \lt ε$ for every $n \geq n_ε$. Let $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ be sequences with positive integers and let $c_n = a_n + b_n$. Show that $(c_n)$ is a "*zero-sequence*" if and only if both $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are "*zero-sequences*".

Can someone please explain with words what the definition of a "*zero-sequence*" means and why it is interesting to know wether a sequence is a "*zero-sequence*", i.e. what unique properties do  "*zero-sequences*" have? You may assume that I have no previous knowledge of what this type of sequences are about and that I am not familiar with sequences in general.

Comment: Well, it's an odd definition.  Since you are restricting yourself to integers, then taking any $\epsilon <1$ we see that the definition requires that all the $a_n$ beyond some point must be $0$.  As this clearly implies the statement in the definition we see that we might as well have used this as the definition.  Of course, this wouldn't be true if we had positive reals (or rationals) instead of positive integers.

Comment: Side note:  if "positive integer" here excludes $0$ then there are no examples of "zero-sequences" as the condition can't be met even for, say, $\epsilon = \frac 12$.  But perhaps they didn't mean to restrict to integer sequences?

Comment: Maybe they just want to restrict the indices $n$ to be positive integers?

Comment: @SteffenPlunder pardon me, I wrote integers one time to many, note how it is supposed to be " A sequence $(a_n)$ of positive numbers ..." and not integers.

Comment: It's just a sequence of positive numbers with limit $0$ if I'm reading it right.

Comment: @lulu It was meant to be restricted to positive numbers and not positive integers, sorry.

Comment: Would you like the proof? Perhaps that would be most insightful...

Comment: @saulspatz then what is the meaning of explicitly expressing all the set conditions for $n$ and epsilon?

Comment: @MattAPelto Gladly, because I doubt that I will be able to solve it on my own.

Comment: shall I write it as if both sequences are sequences of positive numbers? There is not much difference if we simply assume both sequences are just zero-sequences.

Comment: Basically it just means a sequence that converges to zero. The nice thing is that we can add finitely many zero-sequences to say a sequence $\{x_n\}$ where $x_n$ converges to $x$, and we still get that the sum of these sequences converges to $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a bit open. However, here is one possible explanation of convergences with words:

*"A sequence converges to zero, if every $\varepsilon$-ball around $0$ contains all elements of the sequence with just finitely many exceptiones."*

(With $\varepsilon$-ball, I refer to the interval $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$. In higher dimensions this would be replaces by the ball of all points which have distance less than $\varepsilon$ to $0$.)

**How does this relate to your definition?**

1. First we descide which $\varepsilon$ value we choose. (or in my terms, which $\varepsilon$-ball around zero.) 
   However, it is important to make sure that everything we do holds for all possible choices we do here.
2. Saying that only finitely many exceptions are allowed, can be translated to
   "there is one last outliner, after which all other elements of the sequence remain in the $\varepsilon$-ball". Let us use a number $n_{\varepsilon}-1$ to denote the indices of that last outliner.

Notice that the value $n_{\varepsilon}$ depends on the choice of $\varepsilon$.

3. Saying that all other elements after the last outliner are inside the $\varepsilon$-ball, is nothing else then
   $$
   a_n \in (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon), \quad \text{for all } n \geq n_{\varepsilon}
   $$
   Since your numbers of the sequence are positive, can replace this by
   $$
   a_n < \varepsilon, \quad \text{for all } n \geq n_{\varepsilon}
   $$

**Why do we care for zero-sequences?**

- If $a_n$ denotes the error of an approximation, where $n$ is the level of details of our simulation. Than it is quite natural to ask, if we somehow get arbitrary close to $0$ with out error.
  Here $\varepsilon$ can be seen as the largest error we tolerate. And $n_{\varepsilon}$ is the number after which we stay within the error tolerance. Convergence plays a big role in numerics and applied math.
- However, there are arbitrary many applications within and outside of mathematics.
  Convergences allows us to approximate. It allows us to find new numbers (like real numbers as the limit of rational numbers). We can show that equations have solutions with convergences, ...

The list of applications is endless. Convergences is at the very core of mathematical analysis.

- Zero convergences is related to convergence to any value, via
  $a_n - C$ is a zero sequence, if and only if $a_n$ convergences to $C$.